# React on https cant communicate Node.js API on https(ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

I have a problem. I have frontend wrote in React, that calls a simple API in Node.js for some data. Locally it works fine, communicates great ( because locally it was made thru http requests).
When it comes to deployments, the problem occurred.
Front end deployed and accessible thru (sample) https://my.web.app

```
fetch(`https://122.122.122.122:4000/getData`, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        start: reformatYear(startDate.subtract(1, "year")),
        end: reformatYear(lastDate),
      }),
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);}
```

Back end look like:

```
const express = require("express");
const https = require("https");
const fs = require("fs");
const cors = require("cors");
const mainRouter = require("./routes/mainRouter");

const key = fs.readFileSync("./ssl.key");

const cert = fs.readFileSync("./ssl-certificate.crt");
const options = {
  key: key,
  cert: cert,
};

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use("/", mainRouter);

https.createServer(options, app).listen(4000, () => {
  console.log("Server running on port 4000 (HTTPS)");
});
```

And now, when I run my app I get this error:

```
POST https://122.122.122.122:4000/getData net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID
```

I have gernerated ssl via openssl providing host as : 122.122.122.122

Does anybody can help with solving this isssue?

Comment: A self-signed certificate will not be trusted by the client unless you explicitly add it or the issuer CA explicitly as trusted into the  browser. Otherwise man in the middle attacks would be easy, since everybody could just create arbitrary certificates and the browser would trust these.

Comment: Sound logical. But  is there a way to solve it somehow? The only way to buy certificate? Application will be used by other users so see some data , that is fetched from my server.

Comment: If it is used by other users then you need to get a certificate trusted by these users. Note that you can get such certificates for free for domains (but probably not pure IP addresses) from Let's Encrypt and others.